# window form text only changes after exit method

Tags: winforms, event-handling, delegates, eventhandler

I have this simple method that should change the text of a label when a button it's clicked.
When I click this, the all the label text doesn't change before the method has finished it's work.
so, the final result is I only  get the final text : "Task ended!"
How can I  change the before I finished the method ?

```
private void Go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           label1.Text = "Task started ....";
           Thread.Sleep(5000);
           label1.Text = "Task ended!";

        }
```

Comment: The UI is not going to update until it leaves the button click event. So, you will never see the line of code…  `label1.Text = "Task started ....";` … executed.

Comment: You’re blocking the UI thread so it can’t process the changes. You need to either run your actual workload in a background thread, or instruct the UI to draw itself after changes (not recommended, since you shouldn’t block UI thread)

Comment: You can try and add `this.Refresh();` before the sleep call, however, as already noted, sleeping on the UI thread is not a good idea.

Comment: `private async void Go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { \\[..] await Task.Delay(5000); \\[..] }` -- You should probably actually run and await a Task instead of setting an arbitrary *wait time*, so the Label is set before the Task is run nd after the Task returns (if you're really running a Task).